# How to change value of variable inside of Void function?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, function

I have a function

```
public func lastActivityFor(userName: String) -> String {
    var lastSeenInfo = "date"

    OneLastActivity.sendLastActivityQueryToJID((userName), sender: OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppLastActivity) { (response, forJID, error) -> Void in
        if let timeInSeconds = response?.lastActivitySeconds() {
            let time: NSNumber = NSNumber(unsignedLong: timeInSeconds)

            switch timeInSeconds {
            case 0:
                lastSeenInfo = "online"
            case _ where timeInSeconds > 0 && timeInSeconds < 60:
                lastSeenInfo = "last seen \(timeInSeconds) seconds ago"
            case _ where timeInSeconds > 59 && timeInSeconds < 3600:
                lastSeenInfo = "last seen \(timeInSeconds / 60) minutes ago"
            case _ where timeInSeconds > 3599 && timeInSeconds < 86400:
                lastSeenInfo = "last seen \(timeInSeconds / 3600) hours ago"
            case _ where timeInSeconds > 86399:
                let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:-time.doubleValue)
                let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
                lastSeenInfo = "last seen on \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))"
            default:
                lastSeenInfo = "never been online"
            }
        }
    }
    return lastSeenInfo
}
```

but when it's done, my `lastSeenInfo` variable doesn't change and still equal to "date".

When I call it from my other file:

```
print(OneLastActivity.sharedInstance.lastActivityFor("username_here"))
```

it prints

```
date
last seen some time ago
```

so it works asynchronously how I see. How can I fix it? But I want to fix it without `dispatch_async`. How can I modify my function without touching nested function and `-> Void` part?

Comment: if you are using blocks, use __block var lastSeenInfo = "date"

Comment: @GauravSrivastava `__block var lastSeenInfo = "date"`? What it means?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the request/response is async in nature. The old value is being returned before the result has finished.

Two solutions:
Either make the variable a class instance and mutate it. making it void return.
OR
Wait for the block to finish but that is risky and ill-advised from a design point of view

Why not have a class instance and use the didSet method?
in your class (view controller?)

```
public func lastActivityFor(userName: String) {

OneLastActivity.sendLastActivityQueryToJID((userName), sender: OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppLastActivity) { (response, forJID, error) -> Void in
    if let timeInSeconds = response?.lastActivitySeconds() {
        let time: NSNumber = NSNumber(unsignedLong: timeInSeconds)

        switch timeInSeconds {
        case 0:
            self.lastSeenInfo = "online"
        case _ where timeInSeconds > 0 && timeInSeconds < 60:
            self.lastSeenInfo = "last seen \(timeInSeconds) seconds ago"
        case _ where timeInSeconds > 59 && timeInSeconds < 3600:
            self.lastSeenInfo = "last seen \(timeInSeconds / 60) minutes ago"
        case _ where timeInSeconds > 3599 && timeInSeconds < 86400:
            self.lastSeenInfo = "last seen \(timeInSeconds / 3600) hours ago"
        case _ where timeInSeconds > 86399:
            let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:-time.doubleValue)
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
            self.lastSeenInfo = "last seen on \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))"
        default:
            self.lastSeenInfo = "never been online"
        }
    }
}
}


var lastSeenInfo:NSDate? {
    didSet {
        //update display or something
    }
}
```

Comment: where to paste here? How it will look in my func case?

Comment: Updated response to include your method revised. I have assume it is within your view controller, does this make sense?

Comment: no, it provides a lot of errors with other connected files =/

Comment: I'm trying to push you in the right direction. Are those other files referencing this method? Sorry but this will require a little more work than you might have planned because the method is asynchronous, you may need to supply a callback.

Comment: IF you were lazy, you could sleep until the block is finished. and then send the variable out, does that make sense? It's important to do it properly though. How much do you understand about async dispatch?

Comment: not this method, but this file, for example `let lastActivityTest = OneLastActivity()`

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the member to be an optional meaning initialisation is NOT required. please try that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92344/discussion-between-orkhan-alizade-and-mitchell-currie).